# How to convert an integer (time) to HH:MM:SS::00 in Progress SQL

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I need to create a SQL script to convert a integer field to varchar. My database is a Progress DB.
This integer field (nrHoraRegistro) has a timestamp converted in integer.

[image]

Is there a way to write a query to convert it in Progress SQL ?

Kind Regards,
Juliano

Comment: What does the value `54671` mean in terms of time? What's the formula you want to use?

Comment: Hello @TheImpaler,  54671 is 15:11:11 in HH:MM:SS. I got that using 
Disp String(nrHoraRegistro,'HH:MM:SS').

Comment: So the number is the number of seconds since midnight.

Comment: hmm ok, tho.. 
do you know how can i get the HH:MM:SS knowing the number of seconds since midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an [answer](https://community.progress.com/s/question/0D54Q00008GJ52G/time-format-odbc) I have given before:

```
select
   to_char( 
      timestampadd( 
         sql_tsi_second, 
         nrHoraRegistro,
         curdate() 
      ),
      'hh24:mi:ss' 
   )
from
   pub.testtable
```

Comment: Hi thank you !! your solution is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as a workaround I did :

```
SELECT right('00' + to_char(floor(54671/3600)), 2) + ':' +
right('00' + to_char(MOD(54671,3600)/60), 2) + ':' +
right('00' +to_char(MOD(MOD(54671,3600),60)) , 2) as nrHoraRegistro
```

FROM PUB.XXX

Answer (score -1):

You can use this conversion :

SELECT (to_timestamp(54671) at time zone 'UTC')::time

It works forme the result is :

```
Returned value:
+----------+
| 15:11:11 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Hi , using SQL Explorer ?

Comment: It is pure PostgreSQL,, you can replace 54671 by the column name (nrHoraRegistro) in your query, it will work like a charm.

Comment: I'm not using PostgreSQL, i'm using Progress DB